# Embedded Tweets in Vaadin

Tags: java, twitter, vaadin

I am trying to [embed](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) a tweet in Vaadin v7:

```java
    Label oneTweet = new Label();

    String s = "<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\"><p>Four more years. <a href=\"http://t.co/bAJE6Vom\" title=\"http://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/266031293945503744/photo/1\">twitter.com/BarackObama/st…</a></p>&mdash; Barack Obama (@BarackObama) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/266031293945503744\">November 7, 2012</a></blockquote>";
    s = s + "<script async src=\"http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>";

    oneTweet.setValue(s);
    oneTweet.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);

    layout.addComponent(oneTweet);
```

The problem is, Vaadin does not pick up the script file `widget.js`. I tried forcing it by putting 
`@JavaScript( {"http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"} )`
at the beginning of my source code. It picks up the file but does not style the embedded tweet at all. I was wondering if someone has done this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is having the same question, I solved it by calling this at the end of loading a tweet:

```
    String script = "!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=\"http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");";
    Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(script);
```

The javascript snippet comes from the guideline by [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) (Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

Does it work with the ContentMode **Label.CONTENT_XHTML** or **Label.CONTENT_RAW**?  Another guess that comes to mind is to include the script in your gwt.xml file and take it out from the Label.  Good luck.

Comment: Label.CONTENT_XHTML is essentially ContentMode.HTML in Vaadin 7. The problem is not the HTML content, as I can see HTML content in a label when ContentMode is HTML. The problem is that `widgets.js` does not take effect once the label is loaded.